# Definer of Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql

Most of the stored procedures has been created as a root at % or 'someUser' @ localhost
When I copy the procedure to another server, it does not work since the user 'someUser' is not there. The relevant line in dump file is shown below.

```
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50020 DEFINER=`root`@`%`*/ /*!50003 PROCEDURE `SP_Name`(in dt varchar(10))
```

How do I successfully run the procedure on other server without creating an user there?

Comment: Seems a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666286/mysql-definer-in-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

Change the 'username' in the DEFINER clause to the user that is running on the new server.

```
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50020 DEFINER=`[new_server_user]`@`%`*/ /*!50003 PROCEDURE `SP_Name`(in dt varchar(10))
```