# Is `definer` required when creating a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've written all of MySQL procedures as `root@localhost`:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `p_add_user`(...)
```

Trouble is, when deploying to another server, I have to replace `root` with current user and replace `localhost` with current IP, which is annoying.

Is there any way to write procedures so that someone who wants to use my database and procedures would not have to modify the definer of each procedure?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As stated in MySQL documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

```
CREATE
[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
PROCEDURE sp_name ([proc_parameter[,...]])
[characteristic ...] routine_body
```

So, the DEFINER part is not mandatory, just CREATE PROCEDURE should work.

Comment: It says "The DEFINER clause determines the security context to be used when checking access privileges at trigger activation time. More detail is given later in this section."

So when I make sure, procedures are used only by privileged users, I can totally remove whole definer things?

Comment: Yes, I suppose. I think that when you define user's permissions there is a "execute procedures" privilege that can be granted/denied (no sure about that...)

Comment: This will set the definer to be the current user. According to the MySQL doc [Access Control for Stored Programs and Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-programs-security.html): "All stored programs (procedures, functions, and triggers) and views can have a DEFINER attribute that names a MySQL account. If the DEFINER attribute is omitted from a stored program or view definition, **the default account is the user who creates the object**."

Comment: Hi, DEFINER attribute killing me... let me know how to remove this?
Its automatically creating when i create new procedure...  I am using godaddy shared hosting.

Comment: Same problem here, the Definer is a killer. how can I add a procedure without a definer?

Comment: Is there any way to generate the SQL from `SHOW CREATE FUNCTION myFunction` _without_ the `DEFINER` clause?

Answer (score 5):

[EDIT: updated ref page]

You can specify execution privileges by adding the following statement in the procedure body (after declaration):

```
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
```

Example:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `p_add_user`()
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
(...)
```

Doing so, the actual invoker privileges are applied and the `DEFINER` part is omitted (even when it is auto-added during schema import).
Full reference here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-objects-security.html

Comment: This should be the answer.
It perfectly addresses the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE DEFINER=[your_web_user]@% PROCEDURE p_add_user(...)
```

Check it.. probably this will help you, if you want to define the user in your procedure...

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain the attribute DEFINER ?   
% means - it allows any user from any ip address ? Pls. reply me.

I am using godaddy shared host in which DEFINER is automatically created and we cant able to remove that. its mentioned as DEFINER=[databasename]@%  but its not allowing me to communicate the stored procedure from local windows application; but i can able to communicate if i use normal query (like: select * from tablenm ... )

Can any one help me in this regard - please.